# JSP using Java Backends Issue

Tags: java, jsp

I have a very specific question for JSP.

I have a web application running on tomcat, and I have a print method modified by myself. The modified method will print via `System.out.println();`.

However, when I try to use this method in a .jsp file, the output can not show correctly on the web page.

The code is below:

method code:

```
public class ResultsPrinter {
    public static void printResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int ColumnCount = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
        int[] columnMaxLengths = new int[ColumnCount];
        ArrayList<String[]> results = new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String[] columnStr = new String[ColumnCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++) {
                columnStr[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);
                columnMaxLengths[i] = Math.max(columnMaxLengths[i], (columnStr[i] == null) ? 0 : columnStr[i].length());
            }
            results.add(columnStr);
        }
        printSeparator(columnMaxLengths);
        printColumnName(resultSetMetaData, columnMaxLengths);
        printSeparator(columnMaxLengths);
        Iterator<String[]> iterator = results.iterator();
        String[] columnStr;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            columnStr = iterator.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++) {
                System.out.printf("|%" + columnMaxLengths[i] + "s", columnStr[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("|");
        }
        printSeparator(columnMaxLengths);
    }

    private static void printColumnName(ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData, int[] columnMaxLengths) throws SQLException {
        int columnCount = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            System.out.printf("|%" + columnMaxLengths[i] + "s", resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(i + 1));
        }
        System.out.println("|");
    }
    private static void printSeparator(int[] columnMaxLengths) {
        for (int columnMaxLength : columnMaxLengths) {
            System.out.print("+");
            for (int j = 0; j < columnMaxLength; j++) {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("+");
    }
}
```

jsp code:

```
<%
    try {
        ResultsPrinter.printResultSet(connector.query("show tables;"));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
%>
```

The web will be like this:
[image: web]

Comment: `System.out` is **not** writing to the webpage, it's writing to the logs of the web server. You should be using `out`. And you'll need to pass it from the JSP to your method. See also [Passing the out Object to a Method](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSP/PassingtheoutObjecttoaMethod.htm)

Comment: Hi Elliott, `Jsp.Writer` actually works, thank you!